# ASP.NET Core 2 windows authentication working only for load adminstrator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want an intranet site which authenticate users using ad (= administrator) accounts. certain pages, I want to restrict to members of certain ad groups.

as a first step, created website with windows authentication. published it on to my local IIS 10.0. On opening website, the windows login dialog comes up. If I give a user with local admin rights, it will login, for other users it keeps going back to the login screen. Both users in the same domain. What's stopping those users.

How can I enable all domain users to access it.
On razor pages or while routing, how can I restrict certain pages to members of particular ad groups.

Thanks

Comment: type in question title. I meant working only for local adminstrator

Comment: this was happening in edge. Its working fine on IE